# Android how to remove all charachers before the /

Tags: java, string, replace

How can I remove all the characters before the / of a string and _

String as =  `Asia/Kuala_Lumpur`

I want to only have `Kuala Lumpur`

thank

Comment: Have you consulted the javadocs?

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
 yourString.substring(yourString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

or

```
 StringUtils.substringAfter(yourString, "/");
```

and to replace a character

```
your_String.replace("_"," ");
```

Comment: `yourString.substring(yourString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).replace("_", " ");` to remove underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Through `string.replaceAll`

```
String s = "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*/|_", " ").trim());
```

Output:

```
Kuala Lumpur
```